# Mui modal backdrop color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the backdrop color in MUI model . I am tried the backdropProps but its deprecated. how can I achieve this

I am trying like this

```js
    <Modal 
         open={model}  
         maxWidth={'md'} 
         fullWidth 
         sx={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} 
         backDropProps >
```

`backDropProps` I am getting deprecated message

Answer (score 0):

Material UI [deprecated](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/modal/) backDropProps, use `slotProps.backdrop` instead

```
<Modal 
  open={model} 
  maxWidth={'md'} 
  fullWidth 
  slotProps={{ backdrop: { sx: { backgroundColor: 'purple' } } }}>
</Modal>
```